# Merging multiple arrays on shared keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I want to merge multiple arrays into one big array with shared keys.

What I've tried:

```
var conditions = [];
if( aa != undefined )
{
    conditions.push( { "query" : { "must" : {  "aa" : "this is aa" } } } );
}

if( bb != undefined )
{
    conditions.push( { "query" : { "must" : {  "bb" : "this is bb" } } } );
}
```

The above code is giving:

```
[
    {
        "query": {
            "must": {
                "aa": "this is aa"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "query": {
            "must": {
                "bb": "this is bb"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

But I need this:

```
[
    {
        "query": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "aa": "this is aa"
                },
                {
                    "bb": "this is bb"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I am able to do it with PHP but I need to do it in native javascript or using `underscore.js`

Comment: Because I am converting my app from PHP to Nodejs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the object your pushing - push everything to the inner array first - then push the object to the outer array:

```
var conditions = [];
var query = { query: {} };
if( aa != undefined ) {
    if (!query["query"]["must"]) {
        query["query"]["must"] = [];
    }
    //conditions.push( { "query" : { "must" : {  "aa" : "this is aa" } } } );
    query["query"]["must"].push({  "aa" : "this is aa" });
}

if( bb != undefined ) {
    if (!query["query"]["must"]) {
        query["query"]["must"] = [];
    }
    //conditions.push( { "query" : { "must" : {  "bb" : "this is bb" } } } );
    query["query"]["must"].push({  "bb" : "this is bb" });
}

conditions.push(query);
```

Comment: It gives error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'must' of undefined"

Comment: @MohammadShahid -- Edited.

Comment: this only works if he defines the conditions himself. it doesn't work if they exist already and he just wants to merge another object in

Comment: @user2415266 See my answer for an alternative that assumes nothing about the contents of `conditions`

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite trivial, because I see you want to make an array out of the last inner property.

Do those Objects you push into the conditions array already exist or are you defining them yourself?

You can solve your problem with a recursive function like this I believe:

**EDIT: The code produces the exact result you wanted now.**

```
var object1 = {
    query: {
        must: {
            aa: "this is aa"
        }
    }
}

var object2 = {
    query: {
        must: {
            bb: "this is bb"
        }
    }
}

var conditions = {};

function mergeObjects(object, parentObject){
    for(var prop in object){
        if(parentObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            if(typeof parentObject[prop] === "object" && shareProperties(parentObject[prop], object[prop])){
                mergeObjects(object[prop], parentObject[prop])
            }else{
                parentObject[prop] = [parentObject[prop], object[prop]];
            }
        }else{
            parentObject[prop] = object[prop];
        }   
    }
}

function shareProperties(obj1, obj2){
    for(var prop in obj1){
        if(obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

mergeObjects(object1, conditions);
mergeObjects(object2, conditions);
```

Output:

```
"{"query":{"must":[{"aa":"this is aa"},{"bb":"this is bb"}]}}"
```

Comment: I need to merge multiple arrays based on the conditions

Comment: check the code I edited in, this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

For each descendant of `conditions`, check if it exists, create it if it doesn't.

Then, finally, push your new object:

```js
function addCondition(conditions, key, value) {
  conditions[0] = conditions[0] || {};  
  conditions[0].query = conditions[0].query || {};
  conditions[0].query.must = conditions[0].query.must || [];
  
  var o = {};
  o[key] = value;
  
  conditions[0].query.must.push( o );
}
  
var conditions = [];
var aa = 1, bb = 1;

if (typeof(aa) !== 'undefined')
  addCondition(conditions, "aa", "this is aa" );
if (typeof(bb) !== 'undefined')
  addCondition(conditions, "bb", "this is bb" );
if (typeof(cc) !== 'undefined')
  addCondition(conditions, "cc", "this is cc" );

document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(conditions, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```